# spring mvc @Autowired error Unsatisfied 'required' dependency of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, autowired, spring-data-mongodb

I have user service that treat user entity, and @Autowired in user controller class before use user service. so, I got the error:

> `Unsatisfied 'required' dependency of type [class com.yes.service.UserService]. Expected at least 1 matching bean`

here the codes:

userService

```
package com.yes.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.yes.domain.User;
import com.yes.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.yes.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {


    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public User create(User user) {
        user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        user.getRole().setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        // We must save both separately since there is no cascading feature
        // in Spring Data MongoDB (for now)
        roleRepository.save(user.getRole());
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
    public User read(User user) {
        return user;
    }
    public List<User> readAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    public User update(User user) {
        User existingUser = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUserName());
        if (existingUser == null) {
            return null;
        }
        existingUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        existingUser.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        existingUser.getRole().setRole(user.getRole().getRole());
        // We must save both separately since there is no cascading feature
        // in Spring Data MongoDB (for now)
        roleRepository.save(existingUser.getRole());
        return userRepository.save(existingUser);
    }
    public Boolean delete(User user) {
        User existingUser = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUserName());
        if (existingUser == null) {
            return false;
        }
        // We must delete both separately since there is no cascading feature
        // in Spring Data MongoDB (for now)
        roleRepository.delete(existingUser.getRole());
        userRepository.delete(existingUser);
        return true;
    }
}
```

userController (where i use the userService, and the problem is)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;
    @RequestMapping
    public String getUsersPage() {
        return "users";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/records")
    public @ResponseBody UserListDto getUsers() {
        UserListDto userListDto = new UserListDto();
        userListDto.setUsers(service.readAll());
        return userListDto;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/get")
    public @ResponseBody User get(@RequestBody User user) {
        return service.read(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User create(
            @RequestParam String username,
            @RequestParam String password,
            @RequestParam String firstName,
            @RequestParam String lastName,
            @RequestParam Integer role) {

        Role newRole = new Role();
        newRole.setRole(role);
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.setUserName(username);
        newUser.setPassword(password);
        newUser.setFirstName(firstName);
        newUser.setLastName(lastName);
        newUser.setRole(newRole);
        return service.create(newUser);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User update(
            @RequestParam String username,
            @RequestParam String firstName,
            @RequestParam String lastName,
            @RequestParam Integer role) {

        Role existingRole = new Role();
        existingRole.setRole(role);
        User existingUser = new User();
        existingUser.setUserName(username);
        existingUser.setFirstName(firstName);
        existingUser.setLastName(lastName);
        existingUser.setRole(existingRole);
        return service.update(existingUser);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Boolean delete(
            @RequestParam String username) {

        User existingUser = new User();
        existingUser.setUserName(username);
        return service.delete(existingUser);
    }
}
```

spring-data.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder
        properties-ref="deployProperties" />


    <!-- MongoDB host -->
    <mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host.name}" port="${mongo.host.port}" />

    <!-- Template for performing MongoDB operations -->
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate"
        c:mongo-ref="mongo" c:databaseName="${mongo.db.name}" />

    <!-- Activate Spring Data MongoDB repository support -->
    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.yes.repository" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate"/>



    <!-- Service for initializing MongoDB with sample data using MongoTemplate -->
    <bean id="initMongoService" class="com.yes.service.InitMongoService" init-method="init"/>
</beans>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yes.controller"/>



<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<context:property-placeholder
    properties-ref="deployProperties" />

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered 
    as Spring beans. For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the 
    correct base-package -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yes.domain"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yes.dto"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yes.service"/>

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming 
    model. Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only! -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Imports datasource configuration -->
<import resource="spring-data.xml" />
<bean id="deployProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/spring/spring.properties" />
```

the error stack:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.yes.service.UserService com.yes.controller.UserController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.yes.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

EDIT: the question is after fix the errors written in Sotirios Delimanolis answer and comment.

What is the problem cause the error?

**Answer: The problem was what was described in Sotirios Delimanolis answer. The Exact solution described in comments on his answer**

thank you

Comment: Why do you have so many `mongo:repositories` entries? Just keep the first one. The other two are declaring packages that don't exist.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you. I delete that declaration. but the problem still here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application context and servlet context are component scanning over the same packages.

Your application context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yes" />
```

Versus everything in servlet context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yes.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yes.controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yes.domain"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yes.repository"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yes.dto"/>
```

So some beans will be overriden. You don't want this. Your servlet context should scan for `@Controller` beans. Your application context should scan for everything else, but don't make your application context scan for things already scanned by your child (imported) data context. Fix your package declarations so all of these are disjoint.

Comment: thank you again. I take all of the `context:component-scan` from servlet-context to ApplicationContext instead of old one, apart from the `<context:component-scan base-package="com.yes.controller"/>` that left there, 
and the problem solved in userService, but the error moved to userController..., what can i do?

Comment: @yoni Edit your question above with your new contexts.

Comment: @yoni Try removing `<context:component-scan base-package="com.yes.repository"/>` from the application context. That package is already scanned by the spring-data context. If you have `@Component` classes not related to spring-data, you'll have to put them in subfolders that are more specific and reference those.

Comment: @yoni Based on [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html) It doesn't seem to me like you need the `@Repository` annotation. Please post the entire stack trace for the exception. I don't have experience with Mongo configuration.

Comment: @yoni Sorry to ask for so many docs but that's Spring for you. It seems that your servlet context is not inheriting the beans from your application context. Can you post your `web.xml`? Or how you instantiate your contexts.

Comment: thank you so much about your time. I post the web.xml. because my lack of knowledge i don't understand what you mean in 'servlet context is not inheriting the beans from your application context', Can you explain, please

Comment: maybe not in this case but it's good to mention that he can set a filter to ignore @Controller as well if he want to scan the same package

Comment: @yoni Your web application has two contexts: the application context and the servlet context. The application context is the root context (is that the correct name in your `web.xml`?) and all other contexts are children of that context. The children have access (can autowire) beans from the parent but not the other way around. In other words, your application context creates a `UserService` bean which can be injected into the `@Controller` class. Is it `applicationContext.xml` or `root-context.xml`?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis thank you. I fix the reference to applicationContext.xml and this problem solved.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis ohh no, I'm sorry, the problem is still here. my mistake

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I remove all beans scaning from servlet-context.xml and put them all in apllicationContext.xml. This error gone, but i got different error `No property username found for type com.yes.domain.User`, do you have any idea?

Comment: @Yoni Spring uses a specific strategy to retrieve getters and setters for your POJO fields. With what you've above, the field is called `userName`. By providing the name `username`, Spring would try to find (by reflection) a setter called `getUsername`. What you want is `getUserName()`. So either change the property name or the getter/setter names.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you. There is getter `getUserName()`, and setter `setUserName(string)`. Can it's related to my fix?

Comment: @yoni Yes. If you are referencing the field with the String `username`, the getter and setter should be `getUsername()` and `setUsername()`. Notice the lowercase `n`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes!!!!! now its work!!!! I'm grateful to you, you helped me a lot.