# Spring WebService with Endpoint vs no Endpoint

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I need to create a client application for consuming SOAP services. I need to create the client apps from 2 wsdl (from 2 different server applications too)

Here's the code for the **first** Web Service

**EcommPromoWebService.java**

```
package com.ptdam.promo.webservices;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface EcommPromoWebService {
    String sayHi(String text);
    EcommPromoResponse inquiryPromo(EcommPromoRequest promoInquiryRequest);
}
```

**EcommPromoWebServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.ptdam.promo.webservices;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.jws.WebService;

import com.ptdam.promo.utils.C3p0ConnectionPool;

@WebService(endpointInterface="com.ptdam.promo.webservices.EcommPromoWebService")
public class EcommPromoWebServiceImpl implements EcommPromoWebService {

    @Override
    public String sayHi(String text) {  
        System.out.println("sayHi called");
        return "Hello, " + text;
    }

    @Override
    public EcommPromoResponse inquiryPromo(EcommPromoRequest promoInquiryRequest) {
        EcommPromoResponse response = new EcommPromoResponse();
        Connection connInquiry = null;
// and any other stuffs
}
```

and here's the code for the **second** web service:
**TopupWebService.java**

```
package ptdam.emoney.webservice.transactions;
@WebService
public interface TopupWebService {

    @Permission(ServiceOperation.MANAGE_MEMBERS)
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "echoTestResult")
    String echoTest(@WebParam(name = "tx") String tx);

    @Permission(ServiceOperation.MANAGE_MEMBERS)
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "inquiryResult")
    TopupInquiryResponse inquiry(@WebParam(name = "request") TopupInquiryRequest request);

// and any other stuffs
```

**TopUpWebserviceImpl.java**

```
package ptdam.emoney.webservice.transactions;
@WebService(name = "emoneytopup", serviceName = "emoneytopup")
public class TopupWebServiceImpl implements TopupWebService {

// and any other stuffs
}
```

I noticed that there are differences between them. One of it is the **first** webservice has `endPointInterface` on its implementation class, while the **second** hasn't.

when i generate the client code for both of them, using `wsimport` command, it will generate the different class too. The **first** web service will be generated along with the implementation class (`EcommPromoWebServiceImplService` class), while the **second** has no implementation class generated.

So, how to generate the classes for client apps correctly for the **second** webservice? because without implementation class generated, i keep getting NullPointerException on my client apps (kindly check my thread here: [Spring @AutoWired always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900195/spring-autowired-always-null#))

the `wsimport` command i'm using to generate them is `wsimport -keep -verbose <wsdladdress>`